# ionic 2 navControl push issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

i am using ionic 2 for my android application. For page routing i am using

```
this.nav.push(LoginPage);
```

When i push from one page to another it's showing previous page some sections in current page. Because of this my pages are not showing as expected.

```
 Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.6.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 2.0.2
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Please help. I cant find any errors in my console. I don't know why its happening. Please suggest need to follow any particular standard for routing.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot? I don't quite understand what this means: _it's showing previous page some sections in current page_

Comment: Please add your codes and constructors

Answer (score 1):

Add loginPage import to `app.module.ts` file.

```
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
```

Add in constructor like `constructor(private navCtrl: NavController)`

And push the page on stack

```
this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
```

Comment: the same  way i am doing in my application. But previous page styles are also showing

Comment: For style, Are you, using common app.sass (This page style applied throughout the application)?. For separate style, we have to write style code on login.scss file or (.scss file related to that component)